# Trigonometric definite integral question

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

If $$I_n:=\int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^n x dx$$

what is

$$n(I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}) ?$$

I found

$$I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}$$

But it's not a value. It still has integration in it

Comment: Also,I used another site to type tye latex and copied the image.How to use latex in the question itself without copying the image?

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Constraint on $n$?

Comment: I have eliminated all images. Learn by editing the latex expressions I have used. (First step : Enclose the formulas between dollar signs, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $x=\tan ^{-1}(t)$
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \tan^n (x)\, dx=\int_0^1 \frac{t^n}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
$$I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}=\int_0^1 t^{n-1} \frac {t^2-1}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
Now, you could use
$$\frac {t^2-1}{t^2+1}=-1+2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}t^{2k}$$making
$$I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}=-\int_0^1 t^{n-1}\,dt+2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\int _0^1 t^{2k+n-1}\,dt$$
$$I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}=-\frac 1 n+2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2 k+n}$$
$$I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}=-\frac 1 n+\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi \left(\frac{n}{4}+1\right)-\psi   \left(\frac{n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$ Now, if $n$ is large, using the asymptotics of the digamma function
$$n(I_{n+1}-I_{n-1})=-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^3}-\frac{16}{n^5}+\frac{272}{n^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^9}\right)$$

For $n=10$ the exact result is
$$\frac{41}{6}-10 \log (2)\sim -0.09813847226611976083898788$$ while the above truncated series would give
$-\frac{61333}{625000}=-0.0981328$ corresponding to a relative error equal to $0.0058$%.

Comment: Hi, Claude, how are you ? I have some difficulty to unserstand how you transform $I_{n+1}-I_{n-1}=-\frac 1 n+\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi \left(\frac{n}{4}+1\right)-\psi   \left(\frac{n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$ into $n(I_{n+1}-I_{n-1})=-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^3}-\frac{16}{n^5}+\frac{272}{n^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^9}\right)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie. This seems to be correct since $$\psi \left(\frac{n}{4}+1\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n^4}-\frac{32}{n^6}+\frac{544}{n^8}+O\left
   (\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, Claude. Thank you for your answer. I fully understand now. I just made a numerical check: the precision is baffling...

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you. How are you doing in this terrible time ?

Comment: Fine, as far as it can be said in this period of low social interaction.  What about you ? We have had the pleasure to meet our grandchildren 2 weeks ago, 6 months after the last time we met them. Waiting for a jab in a future that looks less distant now...

Comment: @JeanMarie. It is OK but a boring time !! I am doing more research than I never did just to be sure that my brain still works ... a little. Cheers :-)